# Knowing $g_2 = \sum'_{m,n}\frac{1}{(m \omega_1 + n \omega_2)^4}$, what is $f(z)= \sum'_{m,n}\frac{1}{(z+m \omega_1 + n \omega_2)^4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$\omega_1 =1$ and $\omega_2 = e^{i \pi /3}$. I know $g_2 = \sum'_{m,n}\frac{1}{(m \omega_1 + n \omega_2)^4}$, which is an Eisenstein series. The primed sum excludes $m=n=0$. Wolfram Mathematica gives the numerical values.

How do I numerically calculate $f(z)= \sum'_{m,n}\frac{1}{(z+m \omega_1 + n \omega_2)^4}$, for a given $z$? Is this a well known function?

Answer (score 2):

$f(z)+\frac1{z^4}$ is an elliptic function with a single periodic pole of order $4$ and Laurent series

$\frac1{z^4}$+ the questions $g_2+ \dots \;$

With  [Weierstrass's elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) $\wp$, the Laurent series for $\wp^2$ is $\frac1{z^4}$+ a different constant $+ \dots \;$, so the difference between these two functions is a pole-free elliptic function, which can only be constant.

Finding that constant and using a computation method for $\wp$ should work.